# change Language in android using Localization

Tags: android, localization

I need to change localization of  labels in my app. I have created two string folders for English and Hindi language. When I change Localization it’s working fine and all label show in hindi.

```
private void setLanguage(Boolean changeLang) {
    if (changeLang) {
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("hi", "IN"));
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config = viewDashboard.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = new Locale("hi", "IN");
        viewDashboard
                .getBaseContext()
                .getResources()
                .updateConfiguration(
                        config,
                        viewDashboard.getBaseContext().getResources()
                                .getDisplayMetrics());

    } else {
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "EN"));
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config = viewDashboard.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = new Locale("en", "EN");
        viewDashboard
                .getBaseContext()
                .getResources()
                .updateConfiguration(
                        config,
                        viewDashboard.getBaseContext().getResources()
                                .getDisplayMetrics());

    }
}
```

But  It also change date picker language to Hindi which I don’t need.
In same way  few textviews also show Hindi fonts i.e where I have set  date from date picker or show total amount after calculation and Dialog box ‘OK’ and ‘Cancel’ convert into Hindi that I don’t want.
My question is how can  I prevent date picker and dialog box button label from converting to Hindi after changing localization programmatically.

Comment: yes.the data of datepicker will change automatically.

Comment: But i think you have set text for that from your string.xml file.

Comment: no....my mean to say that in datepicker what type of data entered?? means date or just any type of string array ?? And for that string array you have set string.xml file

Comment: You have to first load your Locale and after that save it to shared preference and after that whenever you are changing the language then also call SaveLocale method to it.

Comment: yes.i m getting same error right now.

Comment: i am implementing with my live app.and your suggestion is not properly work..please give some other solution.

Comment: But whenever I try to give solution then are not present here..And also i told you yesterday that post ur screen shot or mail me... So i will defenetly help you

Comment: And i think this is display because in string.xml file you have set the string for date by mistake....Otherwise you had not save your localization properly.

Comment: force close is there?

Comment: no..not to get force close.but localization is by default change language of my app.
for ex.if u change language of android device and change language then same as for localizaiton.localization is same as change langauge of android device from setting menu.
so i have only 1 solution to be change language of localization.
i have manualy set string from java file.

Comment: Ok...i am also working on this type...So can you come to Hello World... So it is easier to solve it

Comment: In my case what happen that after change language it is not saved after the app force close from device.

Comment: please put your code here .i will check ur code..

Comment: @dipali.... Are you changing the language from android device manually using Preference Activity for localization?

Comment: In your code,why r u use fragment?

Comment: Because there is requirement for it and  i have also used many views in my app so on.... But i don't know how to solve this?? Suggestion made by any other is the same which i have already implemented.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35270/discussion-between-shani-goriwal-and-dipali)

Comment: @dipali did you get..????

Comment: @dipali have you resolve this one?

Comment: yes..i have solved as set text in your whole app manually.i can not get proper solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this i think it will be help full for u.Just pass two parameter to this method one is language and other is activity where you are calling this method.

```
public static void setLocale(String language, Activity activity)
{
    Locale locale= new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;

    thisActivity = activity;

    thisActivity.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, thisActivity.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: But It also change date picker language to Hindi which I don’t need. In same way few textviews also show Hindi fonts i.e where I have set date from date picker or show total amount after calculation and Dialog box ‘OK’ and ‘Cancel’ convert into Hindi that I don’t want. My question is how can I prevent date picker and dialog box button label from converting to Hindi after changing localization programmatically.

Comment: for date picker and other text view you are setting value form string folder.if yes then don't take that value from their. set it directly.

Comment: no,i m not setting date picker and other text view value from string folder.for ex.i have set total amount base on calculation.its calculate programmatically.please give me some other solution.

Comment: have u created two different folder in resource 1)values and 2)values-hi and for every view where you want to set text like it. e.g. txtvwTitle.setText(R.string.title); and check condition at launching application that which locale it set and set value to view from that particular folder.

Comment: yes,i already created two folder.and i put text in values-hi folder that i want.but i don't put date picker and other text view (for ex,. total amount textview) text in this folder.its set automatically when i change language.